# Make a div slide up on click and hover using css3 transitions

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I was wondering if someone can help me. I would like to create an on click and hover effect that brings up a div over another div as a sort of overlay. I would preferably like to use css3 transitions but if i have to do it with jquery i will do.

I have found a few things online such as http://jsfiddle.net/UezUj/1/ however this is more of a slide toggle effect and it goes the wrong way. I would like to create something like http://www.ashtonsmith.co.uk/ (if you hover over distribution and logistics) but where the title slides up to reveal the content.

```
        <div class="col-md-4 box__industries">
                <div>
                <div class="image fill">

            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" width="363"   height="159">

                </div>
                <div class="content">
                  <h5>Title</h5>
                   This is my content
                </div>

                </div>
              </div>
```

I would like the div .content to slide up over the image on click and on hover.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try the code below:

```css
.box_industries
{
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box_industries .content
{
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.9 );
  bottom: -100%;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition: bottom 0.5s ease;
  width: 100%;
}
.box_industries:hover .content
{
  bottom: 0%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-4 box_industries">
     <div>
         <div class="image fill">
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" width="363"   height="159">
         </div>
         <div class="content">
             <h5>Title</h5>
                 This is my content
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this? I have just written some simple code to make it easier for understanding. Let me know your comment If any.

```css
.box-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/200/200/') #808080 no-repeat center center;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*hidden the content inside*/
}
.box-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 200px;
  /*make the content lies under wrapper*/
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.8);
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  /*make the smooth transition in 0.3s*/
  color: #fff;
}
.box-wrapper:hover .box-content {
  top: 0;
  /*bring the content back*/
}
```

```html
<a class="box-wrapper" href="#">
  <div class="box-content">
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Though, in this one the text is below the picture and only css, no js. This is in codepen. Hope it helps.

http://codepen.io/the-afshin/pen/mEBNjA

But here is the css anyway:

```
.wrapper {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
.image {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
.content  {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
   border: 2px solid red;
   display: inline-block;
 }

.main:hover {
   transform: translateY(-100px);
   transition: transform 2s;
 }
```

And the html:

```
<div class="col-md-4 box__industries wrapper">

            <div class="image fill">

        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" width="363"   height="159">

              </div>                
            <div class="main">
              <h5 class="content">Title</h5>
              <p class="content">This is my content</p>
            </div>

            </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.box_industries
{
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box_industries .content
{
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.9 );
  bottom: -100%;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition: bottom 0.5s ease;
  width: 100%;
}
.box_industries:hover .content
{
  bottom: 0%;
height:10%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-4 box_industries">
     <div>
         <div class="image fill">
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/" width="363"   height="159">
         </div>
         <div class="content">
             <h5>Title</h5>
                 This is my content
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```